# Package Installation

Tags: package-management

I am primary Windows User and now Learning Linux. There different Software which I need to Install in Linux. I don't have Internet Connection at home. Is there any way that I can download Software in the office using Windows then Install in to Linux. Like Windows you can download Software (setup file .exe) simply run

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ubuntu!

Ubuntu (and Debian + its derivates) uses `.deb` package, which could be considered as equivalent to windows `.exe` file.

If you want to install software manually without internet connection, you can download .deb files from Ubuntu repository 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/

First, choose your distribution (I assume you are running 16.04 LTS = Xenial), pick what package do you need and download it according to your architecture (32b or 64b)

When you have your file downloaded, install it by either double-clicking, which will open Software center, from where you can confirm installation, or, if you are interested in more sophisticated way, you can open terminal  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

`cd "name_of_directory_where_you_put_the_file"`

`sudo dpkg -i "nameofthepackage.deb"`

It may eventually happen, that you won't be able to install some package due to the missing dependencies. This is difficult to fix without the Internet connection for the new user, tho. But you can use the error output and look for the packages stated as missing.

Good luck and if you had any questions, feel free to ask in comments, or by editing your question, eventually by creating new one.

Comment: Hey Thanks Michal. great Help, easy explanation

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Mate 1.2
vkadam@Ubuntu-Mate:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
vkadam@Ubuntu-Mate:~

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cube. It is a portable package manager you can use to download applications in another computer with internet connection (Your Windows computer) and install it back to your Ubuntu computer, offline.

Below site created a demo on how to use it:
https://www.unixmen.com/camicri-cube-server-an-offline-and-portable-package-manager-for-debian-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/

You can download it here: 
https://launchpad.net/cube-server/+download

But please check the tutorial first, it will guide you on how to set up this application in Ubuntu and Windows:
https://launchpad.net/cube-server/trunk/0.1/+download/cube-server-tutorial.pdf

Comment: great will try and let you know.....