# How to resolve “Failed to download repository information

Tags: apt

I need to download the repositories software  for the ubuntu bionic beaver and store them on an external hard drive so i can access them without the internet. 
On the ubuntu website i see the software in pool but how do i get them downloaded all at once without doing them individually, as there are numerous software

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of space (>100GB) you can use apt-mirror to download the whole ubuntu repository onto your drive and copy that over to an offline computer. It is very similar to apt and its configuration. It uses a file /etc/apt/mirror.list where you list where to store and what to download in a syntax like in apts sources.list file. If you are familiar with apt, you find  apt-mirror easy to work with.

If you have several networked offline computers, and you have a web server (e.g. apache2) installed, you put in in a directory of the web server. Then you can use the offline repository just as the normal repository and just change the addresses in the /etc/apt/source.list file to your server.

For how to setup and use apt-mirror see e.g. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/apt-mirror.1.html or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AustralianTeam/LocalAptMirrors
I am using the system for a long time and it is very good. I even download PPAs for offline use with it. To follow the descriptions I guess a basic understanding of Linux may be required. Also one should already feel familiar with using the command line.

EDIT: 
***Alternative***
Not for full repositories, but for bridiging Online-Offline there is only one tool that I know of doing that. Its fully GUI controlled. You need to install on both an internet connected PC and you offline PC. You select programs you want to have and store them for offline use. That works fine.

- https://launchpad.net/cube-server
- See the second answer for this post: [Package Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842393/package-installation). It is from the Cube developer

  - it also links to this tutorial: https://launchpad.net/cube-server/trunk/0.1/+download/cube-server-tutorial.pdf

hope it helps

Comment: still not getting to do the complete downloads, i am seeing the individual files though. would like some one to walk me through it